Unable to exclude dev dependencies from production build using pnpm and turbo
I am using pnpm as package manager.
Turbo to build by project.
I am using typescript.
Everything is working fine but the issue is as follows.
I have to pnpm install --prod to exclude dev dependencies that work perfectly, but when I don't have the dev dependencies the turbo build starts failing.
I tried installing Turbo globally but that doesn't work because it needs all the types and dev dependencies to complete the build successfully.
I couldn't find a way to exclude the dev dependencies safely while the build process also not get effected.
I am new to turbo and pnpm. Need assistance, thanks in advance.

The challenge arises because your build process itself relies on some dev dependencies, such as TypeScript types, linters, or build tools like Turbo.
Even though you're trying to exclude dev dependencies for production, the build process often relies on these dev dependencies to function correctly. If you exclude them, the build fails because the necessary tools and types are missing.
Try this out and let me know:
pnpm install
pnpm run build
pnpm prune --prod


pnpm prune --prod Juse removed the dev dependencies from node_modules but my build still contains the dev dependencies

This is maybe a followup question, but isn't a package incorrectly defined if its non-dev build uses dev dependencies? Otherwise such a package can never work with pnpm install -P, which seems wrong? Or am I (and presumably also the OP) misunderstanding what the point of -P and dev dependencies is?
